# Srinivasa Ramanujan conjectures

Tags: reference-request, conjectures

I searched internet for the whole list of conjectures by Srinivasa Ramanujan , but its not fruitful . I came to know that recently a book of Ramanujan was out and contains many conjectures related to summations .

Please link the reference of Srinivasa Ramanujan conjectures .

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it have been " Ramanujan's Lost Notebook" by George Andrews and Bruce C. Brendt, this is a work of which four volumes have been published .Quoting from the preface:

"This is the fourth of five volumes that the authors are writing in their exam ination of all the claims made by S. Ramanujan in The Lost Notebook and Other Unpublished Papers. Published by Narosa in 1988, the treatise contains the “Lost Notebook,” which was discovered by the first author in the spring of 1976 at the library of Trinity College, Cambridge. Also included in this publication are partial manuscripts, fragments, and letters that Ramanujan wrote to G.H. Hardy from nursing homes during 1917–1919. Although some of the claims examined in our fourth volume are found in the original lost notebook, most of the claims examined here are from the partial manuscripts and fragments. Classical analysis and classical analytic number theory are featured."